# Security proof for TLS 1.x

Tags: diffie-hellman, protocol-design, tls

In [JKSS12](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/219.pdf), a proof for the handshake in TLS-DHE 1.2 is given, assuming (among other things) the PRF-ODH hypothesis on the PRF used to derive keys.

It is also stated that, if TLS 1.2 was to be modified to follow more closely the $\Sigma_0$ protocol from Canetti-Krawczyk; this protocol could be provably secure under a (weaker) DDH assumption instead of the PRF-ODH assumption (as it is the case for IKE protocol). This modification seems fairly straightforward, even though impossible to deploy at the time of this publication.

More recently, concerning TLS 1.3, existing proofs are still under the PRF-ODH hypothesis (see for example this [Thesis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/89299641.pdf) from Dowling, p153).

What was the rationale behind TLS 1.3 and why a move towards $\Sigma_0$-like protocols has not been made, as suggested in [JKSS12](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/219.pdf) ? A DDH hypothesis seeming more satisfying than a (stronger) PRF-ODH assumption, even if only for "security common ground" between TLS and IKE. My interest is mainly regarding TLS with ephemeral DH.

Comment: You may be interested in https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/844